# Geoserver 2.5.2 CQL BBOX filter

Tags: geoserver, openlayers, cql-filter

Trying to use CQL bounding-box filter, but get a strange result like this:

```
loadFeatures({"type":"FeatureCollection","totalFeatures":15640,"features":[]})
```

It showing a total 15640 features in that bbox, but why there are no list of them and "features" are just empty list?

This is my CQL filter:

```
http://loom-gis.geo.ut.ee:8080/geoserver/ermas/ows?service=WFS&version=1.1.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=ermas:testdata_geopnt&outputFormat=text/javascript&format_options=callback:loadFeatures&maxFeatures=50&srsname=EPSG:3301&EPSG:3301&CQL_FILTER=%28BBOX%28geometry,494981.10875,%206437855.3625,%20684824.8587499999,%206569105.3625%29%29
```

Answer (score 2):

you have to declare that you use EPSG 3301 and not EPSG 4326 for the BBOX with wfs in version 1.1.1.:
" If the crsuri is not specified then the 2-D coordinates shall be specified using decimal degrees and WGS84"
( http://augusttown.blogspot.de/2010/08/mysterious-bbox-parameter-in-web.html )

Just add a crsuri at the end:

[http://loom-gis.geo.ut.ee:8080/geoserver/ermas/ows?service=WFS&version=1.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=ermas:testdata_geopnt&outputFormat=text/javascript&format_options=callback:loadFeatures&maxFeatures=50&srsname=EPSG:3301&BBOX=494981.10875, 6437855.3625, 684824.8587499999, 6569105.3625,EPSG:3301](http://loom-gis.geo.ut.ee:8080/geoserver/ermas/ows?service=WFS&version=1.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=ermas:testdata_geopnt&outputFormat=text/javascript&format_options=callback:loadFeatures&maxFeatures=50&srsname=EPSG:3301&BBOX=494981.10875,%206437855.3625,%20684824.8587499999,%206569105.3625,EPSG:3301)

with version 1.0.0 it works, too:

```
$.ajax("http://loom-gis.geo.ut.ee:8080/geoserver/ermas/ows?service=WFS&version=1.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=ermas:testdata_geopnt&outputFormat=text/javascript&format_options=callback:loadFeatures&maxFeatures=50&srsname=EPSG:3301&CQL_FILTER=%28BBOX%28geometry,494981.10875,%206437855.3625,%20684824.8587499999,%206569105.3625%29%29",
    { dataType: "jsonp" }
).done(function ( data ) {
    console.log('done will never be called, unfortunately...');

});

function loadFeatures(data) {
    var map=new OpenLayers.Map("map");
    map.addLayer(new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM());
    console.log("jetzt");
    var vector = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector({
    });

  var geojsonParser = new OpenLayers.Format.GeoJSON(
  {
  'internalProjection': new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:900913"),
                    'externalProjection': new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:3301")
  });
  vector.addFeatures(geojsonParser.read(data));
     map.addLayer(vector);
    map.zoomToExtent(vector.getDataExtent());
    console.log(data);

};
```

see http://jsfiddle.net/expedio/nxd1t2t3/